# Cordova QRScanner plugin not showing camera view in Ionic v1 app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

I have read through about 15 related SO threads but nothing in those threads has helped to get the scanner to display.  So far, I am only testing my Ionic v1 app on Android. I am using Ionic's tabs and on one tab server based content is loaded with an ng-repeat. At the top is a button to scan a QR Code, the button click initializes `$scope.scannerOpen()` and should show the scanner with these function calls:

```
  $scope.scannerOpen = function() {
    QRScanner.prepare(onDone) ; // prepare the camera, check permissions
  }

  function onDone(err, status){
    if (err) {
     // here we can handle errors and clean up any loose ends.
     console.error("Camera: Prepare error - " +err);
     return ;
    }
    $scope.scannerStatus() ;
  }  

  $scope.scannerStatus = function() {
    QRScanner.getStatus(function(status){
      if (status.authorized) { // authorized, show scanner 
        console.log("camera: authorized") ;
        $scope.scannerShow() ;
      } else if (!status.authorized && !status.denied) { // never asked, prompt user
        console.log("camera: never asked") ;
        QRScanner.prepare(onDone) ;
      } else if (status.denied && status.canOpenSettings) { // user previously denied prompt, ask user to change settings
        console.log("camera: denied") ;
        QRScanner.openSettings() ;
      } else if (status.restricted) {  // phone settings restricted
        console.log("camera: restricted") ;      
        alert("Camera is restricted, unable to ask for permissions or display phone camera settings.")
      }
    });  
  }

  $scope.scannerShow = function() {
    // Make the webview transparent so the video preview is visible behind it.
    console.log("Camera: Show Scanner") ;
    QRScanner.show();
  }
```

My console is showing me AUTHORIZED and SHOW SCANNER messages - but the camera scanner does not display. I then went through my rendered dom and applied `background:none transparent` to the BODY, ION-VIEW, ION-NAV-VIEW, ION-CONTENT - basically any element that took up the whole display.  Some SO threads mention applying the `background: none transparent` to the `<ion-app>` element but that element is not present in Ionic v1 apps (that I am aware of). But nothing has worked or revealed the camera underneath.

Because I have gone through all major elements in the rendered DOM and added `background:none transparent` and I am still not seeing the scanner I am not even certain if the scanner is there or not.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE 1:

On a whim, I tried scanning a qrcode and to my surprise it worked!  Thats great - but I still can't figure out why its not displaying.  I have gone through the DOM again applying `background: none transparent` everywhere I can think of (and not think of) and the scanner view is still not displaying.

UPDATE 2:

I finally found 3 elements I had to apply `background:none transparent` to or `display:none` - then I could see the camera scanner behind my app.  I know this cant be a final solution but so far its the only thing I was able to do to view it.  I am attaching a visual of the code.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that cares, I had to do some elaborate stuff to make this work cleanly in an Ionic v1 app. And "cleanly" is quite subjective here! PLEASE - if there is a more simple solution please share. I added a frame box with a centering red line through the box around the scanning view screen. If you don't care about a frame box around the camera view, then you can apply display:none or background: transparent to `<ion-content>` - but if you need/want a frame box then you must apply the display/background changes to a main content wrapper div inside the ion-content.

The `scannerBox` function is needed to turn on/off the various elements transparency/display.  They must be turned off and the scanner destroyed before leaving the tab view or the `pane` class, that is used on other Tabs, will make other tab root views transparent (for instance, a white background will turn black) and/or show the camera scanner still showing in behind your tab elements.

Element 3-A: No frame box
Element 3-B: with frame box

In the below code, all the elements that need manipulation

```
<body>
   <ion-nav-bar>
   <ion-nav-view id="appNavView"> // REQUIRED: custom ID assigned
      <div class="pane" nav-view"active" ...>    // REQUIRED 1st element that needs transparency - can't assign ID
         <ion-tabs ...>
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-scanner"  ...>
               <ion-view id="ionViewScanner" class='pane' ...>  // REQUIRED 2nd element that needs transparency - custom ID assigned
                  <ion-content id="ionContentScanner" ...> // OPTION '3-A' element that needs transparency - custom ID assigned,  Use this if you don't care for a frame box
                     <div class="scroll" ....>  // OPTION '3-B' - auto created by Ionic - can't assign ID, height must be adjusted to 100%.
                        <div id="pageWrapper"> // OPTION '3-B' element needs transparency/display:none if frame box wanted
                           <button id="scanOpen" ng-click="scanOpen();" ...>
                           ...ALL MY TAB-PAGE CONTENT .... 
                        </div>
                        <div id="scannerWrapper" style="display:none;background:transparent;height:100%;">  // OPTION '3-B' scanner frame box
                            <div id="scannerTop" style="height:25%;background:white;">
                                <button id="scanStart" ng-click="scanStart()" ...>
                                <button id="scanCancel" ng-click="scanCancel();" ...>
                             </div>
                             <div id="scannerBox" style="height:50%;">
                                <div id="scannerLine" style="height:50%;border-bottom:1px solid red;"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div id="scannerBottom" style="height:25%;background:white;"></div>
                           </div>
                        </div> // end ionic created DIV
                     </ion-content>
```

And then in my controller I have:

```
  var appNavView = document.getElementById("appNavView") ;  
  var divPane = appNavView.children[0] ; 
  var pageWrapper = document.getElementById("pageWrapper") ;
  var scannerWrapper = document.getElementById("scannerWrapper") ;
  var scannerParent = scannerWrapper.parentNode ;

  function scannerBox(x) {
    if (x == 0) { // close
      divPane.style.background = "white" ;
      pageWrapper.style.display = "" ;
      scannerWrapper.style.display = "none" ;
      scannerParent.style.height = "" ;
    } else if (x == 1) { //open
      divPane.style.background = "none transparent" ;
      pageWrapper.style.display = "none" ;
      scannerWrapper.style.display = "" ;
      scannerParent.style.height = "100%" ;    
    }
  }

/// I cut all the prepare/getStatus stuff out - that all remains the same

  $scope.scanOpen = function() {
    scannerBox(1) ;
    QRScanner.show();
  }

  $scope.scanCancel = function() {
    QRScanner.cancelScan(function(status){
      $scope.scannerHide() ;
    });    
  }

  $scope.scannerHide = function() {
    scannerBox(0) ;   
    QRScanner.hide(function(status){
      console.log(status);
    });    
  }

  $scope.scannerDestroy = function() {
    scannerBox(0) ;       
    QRScanner.destroy(function(status) {
      console.log("Camera: destroyed") ;
    }) ;
  }

  //And then hide/destroy scanner when leaving TAB
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.scannerHide() ;
    $scope.scannerDestroy() ; 
  });

  $scope.$on("$ionicView.leave", function(event,data) {
    $scope.scannerHide() ;
    $scope.scannerDestroy() ; 
  }) ;
```